# How can Optimus reach into the time bubble and pull the humans out?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series, transformers-the-last-knight

In the latest *Transformers* movie, one of the bots has a time-bubble gun which slows time in the blast radius.

In one scene, Megatron was caught in it and then one of the Autobots shot a bunch of bullets into it and of course the bullets stop as soon as they enter the bubble. When the bubble is released, all the bullets hit Megatron at once. This made sense to me.

In another scene, Mark Wahlberg is caught in the time bubble (while free falling) and then Optimus reached into the bubble and grabbed the humans to save them.

How come Optimus hand was not affected by the time bubble?

Comment: Presumably for the same reason that the bullet doesn't stop as soon as the front enters the bubble: the entire entity (or at least the majority) must be encased before the effect takes place. Because there is an outside force acting on his arm and Mark inside, it follows along with that.

Comment: Alternatively, you'll notice the bullets don't stop immediately but slow to a halt. That process may take longer depending on the object's mass and speed.